# Can anything be inserted programmatically after the $ sign in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Was just looking at some plugin and I noticed within the plugin they had the following syntax.

```
$.informationTech = {
    validateFormat: function (address) {
      return !!address.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}\s?\$/);
    }
}
```

And then they called the function like `$.informationTech.validateFormat()`.

I was just wondering about `$.informationTech` what does exactly mean in jQuery or what's it a shortcut for ?

Comment: The `$` variable is just a plain old object, as such you can add whatever properties you like to it. Be wary of polluting it with extraneous functions though.

Comment: Just a note, `$` is also used in prototype.js, in which case you will have to "unlink" the `$` variable in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$`, or `jQuery` is an object inside JavaScript, created by jQuery as the main base for its library. Any functionality of jQuery goes inside this variable.

For example, take the following code as an example:

```
$(".flashy").fadeIn(); // fades in all elements with a class of flashy
```

`fadeIn` would be a function inside the `$` variable. Think of it in these terms:

```
var $ = {
  fadeIn: function () {
    // do something
  }
}
```

For the use in your case:

```
$.informationTech = {
  validateFormat: function (address) {
    return !!address.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,4}\s?\$/);
  }
}
```

This is just "piggybacking" on the `$` variable (which should be used for jQuery only) to add in a property called `informationTech`, containing a function called `validateFormat`. (piggybacking is not an actual term, AFAIK, but I like the term, because it makes sense :D)

As another example, if you were to write a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.pluginName = function () {
  // do stuff
}
```

Notice how you write `$.fn.pluginName`. You would run this as:

```
$(".className").pluginName();
```

This is because `$.fn` is a built-in jQuery property, and any functions you put inside there are linked directly after an element selector.

Answer (score 0):

$.informationTech has nothing to do with JQuery, it is only using the "$" variable which is mainly used by JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixing a variable with "$" typically refers to variable that returns a jQuery object specifically. This isn't always the case, but it's whats a lot of developers typically do it for. As such it's no different to any other var deceleration.